# jquery ui map update cluster position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-map

I am building a googlemaps web application that has a series of static markers as well as a series of markers representing staff who are "out on the field" I am able to retrieve a staff members lat, long position via ajax.

But using jquery ui map v3 I cannot update the poistion of the marker with a matching staff ID.

How can i change a markers position and then update the map view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [setPosition()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) method of `Marker` to change the position of a marker !

[Very simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Rsp22/)

Comment: so how could I use this to move a marker and then draw it in the new position?

Comment: @jaget the setPosition method does exactly that see the example

Comment: I am so stupid, turns out I was doing the same as you however, the JSON object I was retrieving uses lat long and I was trying to use it's postcode, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I have another issue I am trying to use, getMarkers() to get an array of markers so I can loop through and check/ update all positions, however I am being told by console log that there is an error with 'apply'. Does this mean anything to you?